# As $x\to \infty$, $x^2-x$ and $\ln^2(1-\frac1x)$ cancel out to 1?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Why is it when I put $\ln^2(1-\frac1x) \cdot (x^2-x)$ into a calculator, the result gets closer to $1$ as $x$ gets bigger.

This would imply that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln^2(1-\frac1x) \cdot (x^2-x) = 1.$$

The part that really confuses me is that as $x$ gets bigger, the $\ln\left(1-\frac1x\right)$ term should go to zero.

I can't seem to find an easy reason as to why this happens.

Comment: Have you pondered the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Note that $\log(1)=0$.

Comment: well it goes to one, but could you explain how this relates to the question? I'm sorry if its obvious but I've slammed my head against this problem for a couple weeks so I'd much rather someone explain it to me like you would a five year-old.

Comment: I can explain it, but not to a five-year-old.  Do you know l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: By Taylor polynomials, $$
(x^2  - x)\left( {\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)^2  = (x^2  - x)\left( {\frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right)} \right)^2  \\ = (x^2  - x)\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \right)} \right) = 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)
$$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln (1-\frac{1}{x})$ does go to $0$, but simultaneously $x^2-x$ goes to $\infty$. A product of such terms may (but doesn't have to) have a non-zero, finite limit.

In this case, substituing $y = -\frac{1}{x}$ we have
$$ \ln^2(1-\frac{1}{x}) \cdot(x^2-x) = \ln^2(1+y) \cdot(\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{y})= \left(\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}\right)^2 \cdot (1+y) $$

If you know that $$ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+y)}{y} = 1 $$ (which can be proven in various ways), then you have
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln^2(1-\frac{1}{x}) \cdot(x^2-x) = \lim_{y\to 0} \left(\left(\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}\right)^2 \cdot (1+y) \right)= 1^2\cdot 1 =1 $$

Comment: $\ln(1-1/x)$ goes zero as $x\to\infty$, you are right in this part. But notice that this is multiplying by $x^2-x$. So, you can write it as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(x^2 \frac{\ln(1-1/x)}{\frac{1}{1-1/x}}\Big)=\infty \ \frac{0}{0}.$$  Does that help little bit?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\left[\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right] \left[\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right] .$$
As $x\to\infty$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\to\frac{1}{e} $$
by the definition of Euler number, the two $\ln$s goes to $-1$:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \ln\frac{1}{e}=-1$$
and $$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\to 1.$$
\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right] \left[\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]\\ &=\ln\frac{1}{e}\ln\frac{1}{e} \cdot 1=(-1)(-1)1=1.\end{align*}

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{x})^x = \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: sure, i will review

Comment: luckily the answer remains the same

Comment: `\to` or `\rightarrow` produces $\to$.  `\longrightarrow` makes it longer